# Replace master fragment using 'if (position == x)'

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, android-fragments

I have a dummy content list containing 3 items but I want each item to open its own activity rather than passing data to the detail fragment. How can I replace the master fragment with a list fragment of my own when a particular list item is clicked? Is it possible to use the `if (position == x)` statement for each of my items? The code below replaces the detail fragment but I want to replace the master fragment instead. I have not seen any tutorials on this as all the ones I've come across are associated with replacing the detail fragment, NOT the master fragment.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    if (mTwoPane) {
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.item_list, fragment)
                .commit();

    } else {
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, ContinentsListActivity.class);
        detailIntent.putExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        startActivity(detailIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your layout containing your master fragment.

Comment: You can check the id passed in `onItemSelected`. However, it depends on which value you pass in onItemSelected method when you call it from onListItemClick.

Comment: that id refer's to the detail fragment container. is it not ?

Comment: @Joseph82 my `onListItemClick` has not been modified since I created the project. As seen below it depends on whatever has been clicked from the dummy content items.

`@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);

        mCallbacks.onItemSelected(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);
    }`

Comment: So, you can compare that id, for example `if("1".equals(id)){ // replace fragment}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use View.setTag() every time you add an item to your list, so later you can retrieve this tag with View.getTag() and identify the selected item.